# Jenkins Schedule build

Tags: scheduled-tasks, jenkins, build

Getting little confusing with the Jenkins build scheduling.

I want to schedule a build that will run at first day of the month, every 6 months.

As for now i have this `H H 1 * *`

But I'm not sure it's correct.

Comment: if answer helped, pls upvote. If it answered your query, also pls tick accepted :). That's how S/O works! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer in [S/0 - How do I schedule jobs in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472740/598141), you probably want:

`H H 1 H/6 *`

That's every 6 months (H/6) on first day (1) at a random hour and minute (H H)  (read right to left).